# Check GPS state (on/off)in cordova android

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, gps

I am successfully implement the geolocation using this (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation) for cordova,however the gps is turned off in the phone `onerror` function is never called.Is there any another way to check the gps is turned on or off.Here is my code

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
//getting location
 lat=position.coords.latitude;
long=position.coords.longitude;

}, function (error) {
        //when gps is off it is never executed
         alert('Unable to get location: ' + error.message);

        });
```

**UPDATE**

`onerror` is executed in **SONY XPERIA T**,but not in other devices (**Micromax,Samsung,Motog**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if this is what you want, but I am using this plugin which works well for me

https://github.com/mablack/cordova-diagnostic-plugin

I think the Geolocation API does not give you an error if the GPS is on/off, just a timeout error if it is not able to get a lock in the time limit you specify, but I tested it a while ago and I might be mistaking.